# I keep getting error that says main is not defined. I just want it to run. It's supposed to let me enter the description, price, and unit

Tags: python

```
class RetailItem:
    # The _init_ method initalizes the attributes.
    def __init__(self, description, units, price):
        self.__description = description
        self.__units = units
        self.__price = price
    # The set_description method acccetps an argument for the retailitem's description.
    def set_description(self, description):
        self.__description = description
    # The set_units method accepts an argument for the retailitem's units.
    def set_units(self, units):
        self.__units = units
    # the set_price method accepts an argument for the retailitem's price.
    def set_price(self, price):
        self.__price = price
    # The set_description methods returns the retailitem's description.
    def get_description(self):
        return self.__description
    # The get_units method returns the retailitem's units.
    def get_units(self):
        return self.__units
    # The get_price method returns the retailitem's price.
    def get_price(self):
        return self.__price
def make_list ():
    #Create an empty list
    item_list = []

    # Add Item Object to the list 
    print ('Enter date for the items')
    keep_going = 'Y'
    i = 1
    while keep_going.upper() == 'Y':
        print('Item n*',i)
        #Get the Item data
        descript = input('Enter the description: ')
        units_Inv = input('Enter the units: ')
        prix = float(input('Enter the price:$'))
        print()
        # Create an instance of the retailitem class
        item = retailitem.RetailItem(descript, units_Inv, prix)
        i += 1
        #Add the Object to the list
        item_list.append(item)
        keep_going = input('Press Y to continue to add Data for item or N to stop: ')
    # return the list
    return item_list


def display_list(item_list):
    for var in item_list:
        print(var.get_description())
        print(var.get_units())
        print(var.get_price())
        print()
#call the main function.
main ()
```

Answer (score 2):

`main` needs to be defined (`def main` doesn't appear in your example, at least). My guess is that you are expecting the following:

```
def main():
    lst = make_list()
    display_list(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly what the error message is telling you:

```
#call the main function.
main ()
```

Where is `main()` defined?

This may be caused by confusion about how Python works vs. other languages. In Python, anything at the global level is executed automatically -- it doesn't need to go in a main function.

So, if you want to run some code, just do it:

```
class RetailItem:
    def __init__(self, description, units, price):
        self.__description = description
        self.__units = units
        self.__price = price
    # etc.

l = make_list()
display_list(l)
```

Typically you would wrap that code at the end in a [`if __name__ == "__main__"` block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do), but it's not required.

Answer (score 0):

you need somewhere

```
def main():
    #function body - whatever you want it to do
```

in this case, what it looks like you want to do is to create an instance of the RetailItem class and then call its methods.

Answer (score 0):

The error says the issue. "main is not defined".
You are calling the main() function at the end but didn't define it anywhere in the code.

```
def main():
     # this is your main function
     list = make_list()
     display_list(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

w.r.t. "I just want it to run": add the following to the top of your code:

```
def main():
    pass
```

Your code will now run. *Technically.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference putting all of the functions together you actually need to declare a function called main() EX:

```
def main():
    makelist()
    displaylist(item_list)
####################################
main()
```